# How to change variables in the main thread from another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, libgdx

Here is my run() function:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        long elapsed = TimeUtils.nanoTime() - startTime;
        Texture currentFrame = connectedAnim.getFrame(elapsed);
        textureToApplyTo = currentFrame;
    }
}
```

In the constructor for this class, I have set `textureToApplyTo` to a Texture variable in my main thread. The problem is, when I set the `textureToApplyTo` in the run() function to `currentFrame`, it only changes it in the class which I set it in. I think the problem is I am making the variable `textureToApplyTo` in this class, as well as the main class but I don't know how else I'd do it... I need a way to change the `textureToApplyTo` variable in the main class from this thread.

Comment: Can you provide more code? Can you use callbacks?

Comment: I think your problem may lie somewhere else. Unless you are creating a separate instance of textureToApplyTo in your thread, which it looks like you are not doing, then your threads are accessing the same instance. Sharing variables among threads is ridiculously easy which is why you have to use mutexes for shared variables. It may help if you post more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add volatile keywork in your textureToApplyTo declaration. Like this

```
 public static volatile Texture textureToApplyTo;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should make the variable a global variable, so when declaring the class, you'd have something like this:

```
public class yourClass
{
    private textureToApplyTo;

    public setTexture(Frame frame)
    {
        textureToApplyTo = frame;
    }
}
```

Once you do this, you can call this method in your `run()` method that you have.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        long elapsed = TimeUtils.nanoTime() - startTime;
        Texture currentFrame = connectedAnim.getFrame(elapsed);
        yourClass.setTexture(currentFrame);
    }
}
```

Comment: It *has* to be defined as a field since `textureToApplyTo` isn't defined in the `run` method at all.

Comment: He says that he declares it twice, in the main, and in the run. So what I said is still a valid answer, if he's creating two variables, both of which appear to be local, then he needs to solve it by creating one variable, a global variable.